# Geolocation & jquery post

Tags: jquery, html, post, geolocation

I have an issue I have been trying for 4 hours and no luck. After I receive the position I need to make a search on database and get a result and then show it in the screen.

The query to the database is done, but the success function never receive the data back, any ideas?

```
   function initiate_geolocation() {  
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query, handle_errors, {enableHighAccuracy:true});  
    } else {
       yqlgeo.get('visitor', normalize_yql_response);
       /*jQuery("#current-location").html("No geolocation support."); */
    }

    return false;
}

function handle_geolocation_query(position){  
    jQuery.post("/index.php?r=location/current", { "latitude": position.coords.latitude, "longitude": position.coords.longitude },
                                        function(data){
                                            jQuery("#zipcode").val(data);
                                        }, "json");    
}  

function handle_errors(error) {
           /*Not important*/
} 

function normalize_yql_response(response)  
    {  
        /*Not important*/
    }
```

Comment: This seems more like a server side problem. Any error in server logs? And are you sure you are /index.php?r=location/current is returning back the data to client?

Comment: Does sound like a server-side issue. Use chromes network tab to see if your post call is returning what you expect.

Comment: Hi, I just found the issue. As I understood before the }, "json"); at the end of the post, was for referring that we are sending json not that we are returning json too, I will post the correct code next, thanks

Comment: I can't post it yet, but since my controller only returns a string no need for datatype, or we can place datatype and return json otherwise will not work.